# ColumnFiltering a DataTables tble using c# server side processing

Tags: c#, datatables

Ok, I have a table which is populated using DataTables server side functionality. I have also added the .ColumnFilter plugin to search on individual columns. My problem is, is that the main global search works fine, but the individual one doesnt do anything.

The DataTables config is as such

```
var getUserNames = function () {
$("#tbl").dataTable({
        "oLanguage": {
            "sZeroRecords": "No records to display",
            "sSearch": "Search on UserName"
        },
        "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'T><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [
            "copy",
            "print",
            {
                "sExtends": "collection",
                "sButtonText": 'Save <span class="caret" />',
                "aButtons": ["csv", "xls", "pdf"]
            }
            ]
        },

        "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, 150, 250, 500, -1], [25, 50, 100, 150, 250, 500, "All"]],
        "iDisplayLength": 20,
        "bSortClasses": false,
        "bStateSave": false,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "WebService1.asmx/GetItems",
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
             aoData.push({ "name": "iParticipant", "value": $("#participant").val
          (), "name": "iArchiveYears", "value": $("#ArchiveYears option:selected").text() });
        },

        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            $.ajax({
                "dataType": 'json',
                "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "type": "GET",
                "url": sSource,
                "data": aoData,
                "success":
                            function (msg) {

                                var json = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
                                fnCallback(json);
                                $("#tbl").show();
                            }
            });
        }
    })
    .columnFilter({

        aoColumns: [
            { type: "text" },
            { type: "text" }
         ]
    });

}
```

with this as my Webservice:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Configuration;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService1
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public WebService1 () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }


    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]

    public string GetItems()
    {
        int sEcho = ToInt(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["sEcho"]);
        int iDisplayLength = ToInt(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["iDisplayLength"]);
        int iDisplayStart = ToInt(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["iDisplayStart"]);
        string rawSearch = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["sSearch"];

        string participant = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["iParticipant"];

        string archiveYears = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["iArchiveYears"];

        DateTime year =  DateTime.Now;

        if (archiveYears == null)
        {
            archiveYears = year.Year.ToString();
        }

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        var whereClause = string.Empty;
        if (participant.Length > 0)
        {
            sb.Append(" Where participant = ");
            sb.Append("'" + participant + "'");
            sb.Append(" AND Year(MsgDate)= ");
            sb.Append("'" + archiveYears + "'");

            whereClause = sb.ToString();
        }
        sb.Clear();

        var filteredWhere = string.Empty;

        var wrappedSearch = "'%" + rawSearch + "%'";

        if (rawSearch.Length > 0)
        { 
            sb.Append(" WHERE Participant LIKE ");
            sb.Append(wrappedSearch);
            sb.Append(" OR MsgDate LIKE ");

            sb.Append(wrappedSearch);                                  

            filteredWhere = sb.ToString();
        }


        //ORDERING

        sb.Clear();

        //Check which column is to be sorted by in which direction     
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["bSortable_" + i] == "true")
            {
                sb.Append(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["iSortCol_" + i]);
                sb.Append(" ");
                sb.Append(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["sSortDir_" + i]);
            }
        }
        orderByClause = sb.ToString();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(orderByClause))

            orderByClause = orderByClause.Replace("0", ", Participant ");
            orderByClause = orderByClause.Replace("2", ", MsgDate ");
            orderByClause = orderByClause.Remove(0, 1);

        }
        else
        {
            orderByClause = "MsgDate ASC";
        }
        orderByClause = "ORDER BY " + orderByClause;

        sb.Clear();

        var numberOfRowsToReturn = "";
        numberOfRowsToReturn = iDisplayLength == -1 ? "TotalRows" : (iDisplayStart + iDisplayLength).ToString();


        string query = @" 
                        declare @MA TABLE(  Participant VARCHAR(50), MsgDate DateTime))
                        INSERT
                        INTO
                            @MA ( Participant, MsgDate
                                FROM [MsgDateDetail] 
                                {4}                   

                        SELECT *
                        FROM
                            (SELECT row_number() OVER ({0}) AS RowNumber
                                  , *
                             FROM
                                 (SELECT (SELECT count([@MA].Participant)
                                          FROM
                                              @MA) AS TotalRows
                                       , ( SELECT   count( [@MA].Participant) FROM @MA {1}) AS TotalDisplayRows            
                                       ,[@MA].Participant
                                       [@MA].MsgDate

                                  FROM
                                      @MA {1}) RawResults) Results
                        WHERE
                            RowNumber BETWEEN {2} AND {3}";


        query = String.Format(query, orderByClause, filteredWhere, iDisplayStart + 1, numberOfRowsToReturn, whereClause);

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MIReporting"].ConnectionString);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch(Exception e )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        var DB=new SqlCommand();
        DB.Connection=conn;
        DB.CommandText=query;
        var  data = DB.ExecuteReader();

        var totalDisplayRecords = "";
        var totalRecords = "";
        string outputJson = string.Empty;

        var rowClass = "";
        var count = 0;

        while(data.Read())
        {

            if (totalRecords.Length ==0)
            {
                totalRecords = data["TotalRows"].ToString();
                totalDisplayRecords = data["TotalDisplayRows"].ToString();
            }
            sb.Append("{");
            sb.AppendFormat(@"""DT_RowId"": ""{0}""", count++);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.AppendFormat(@"""DT_RowClass"": ""{0}""", rowClass);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.AppendFormat(@"""0"": ""{0}""", data["Participant"]);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.AppendFormat(@"""2"": ""{0}""", data["MsgDate"]).Replace("\t", String.Empty);


            sb.Append("},");
        }

        // handles zero records
        if (totalRecords.Length == 0)
        {
            sb.Append("{");
            sb.Append(@"""sEcho"": ");
            sb.AppendFormat(@"""{0}""", sEcho);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(@"""iTotalRecords"": 0");
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(@"""iTotalDisplayRecords"": 0");
            sb.Append(", ");
            sb.Append(@"""aaData"": [ ");
            sb.Append("]}");
            outputJson = sb.ToString();

            return outputJson;
        }
        outputJson = sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1).ToString();
        sb.Clear();

        sb.Append("{");
        sb.Append(@"""sEcho"": ");
        sb.AppendFormat(@"""{0}""", sEcho);
        sb.Append(",");
        sb.Append(@"""iTotalRecords"": ");
        sb.Append(totalRecords);
        sb.Append(",");
        sb.Append(@"""iTotalDisplayRecords"": ");
        sb.Append(totalDisplayRecords);
        sb.Append(", ");
        sb.Append(@"""aaData"": [ ");
        sb.Append(outputJson);
        sb.Append("]}");
        outputJson = sb.ToString();

        return outputJson;
    }

    public static int ToInt(string toParse)
    {
        int result;
        if (int.TryParse(toParse, out result)) return result;           

        return result;
    }

}
```

Now I see when I start to enter into one of the colFilter text boxes in FireBug, that the value are being stored in `HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["sSearch_1"]` but I'm not sure how I can apply this to the individual column and not a global search. I will also need to at a later point add the date-range to filter on the MsgDate col.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

columnFilter doesn't work very well. there is some bug...

i recommand another approach and it work well and more flexible.

you can create your own input like (example):

```
<input id="mysearchfiltercolumn1" type="text" />
```

in your datatable you can add this :

```
var table = $("#tbl").dataTable({
                    //[...]
                    "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
                        aoData.push({ "name": "mycolumn1", "value": $('#mysearchfiltercolumn1').val() });
                        aoData.push({ "name": "mycolumn2", "value": $('#mysearchfiltercolumn2').val() });
                        aoData.push({ "name": "mycolumn3", "value": $('#mysearchfiltercolumn2').val() });
                    }
             });
```

...and you bind your inputs like this :

```
$("#mysearchfiltercolumn1,#mysearchfiltercolumn2,#mysearchfiltercolumn3").bind('keyup',function (event) {
                        table.fnDraw();   
                });
```

and server-side you should see `Request['mycolumn1']` and do make you want in order to give the result.

you can convert `HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["sEcho"]` by `Request['sEcho']` etc...

Comment: Hi Olivier, i fail to see how this filter by Row, and not a global filter. I guess, if i have the filter outside the DT, in a input you like say, then perhaps the best approach would be to use fnFilter(inputValue,colToFilterOn). However, i'm not sure this would filter on the current page or the whole dataset, i shll try tomorrow

Comment: Indeed, you can use `fnFilter(inputValue,colToFilterOn)` but if you use `bServerSide=true`, it'll call an ajax request like `fnDraw()`. If you want to use multiple filter you can add some `oaData.push([...])` in `fnServerParams` for sending all params filters server-side. I updated my response.

Comment: not had chance to look over this today Olivier, will hopefully get the opportunity tomorrow. appreciate your response

Comment: set this up, but it's acting just like the global search does. perhaps i'm missing something

Comment: Olivier, the values are not being pushed into the variables. I set string textbox = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["mysearchfiltercol1"] but it is always empty - it doesnt even appear in firebug under the params section. oddly though the GET call is fired 10 times.

Comment: really struggling to get the values into the params... anyone?

Comment: try this : `aoData.push({ "name": "mysearchfiltercol1", "value": "helloWorld" });` and update your code in your post

Comment: i think i see the error in my ways... testing now, but i had one set of {} for multiple params. where i think they should be for each param being sent. 

typical

Comment: Ok top man, that would for a text box. How would i pass a value from a drop down $('ddBox option:selected') results in [object] being passed